# How to keep object in scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, scope

[image]

I am implementing the following functionality. The majority of the page is created once in my *entryPage.php* file. The "Stage" table is created through an *AJAX* call to *stageArea.php*. My issue is that my data object is created in a `$(document).ready(function() {...}` which cannot be accessed by my other functions outside of the `$(document).ready(function() {...}`.

*entryPage.php*

```
...HTML...
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function() { 

    var dataObject = new DataEntryObj(); // create the data object

    $.post("../stageArea.php", {array : dataObject.dataArray}, function(data){
        $('#stageArea').html(data);
    });
  }
  var DataEntryObj = function(){
    this.dataArray = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0]];
    ....
  }

  function updateData(value, row, index){
    alert("update:" + row + " " + index + " " + value); //values come in OK
    alert(dataObject.dataArray[row][index]); // but the data Object isn't here
    dataObject.dataArray[row][index] = value; // so this cannot be assigned

    $.post("../stageArea.php", {array : dataObject.dataArray}, function(data){
        $('#stageArea').html(data);
    });
  }
</script>
```

**What is a good solution to keep the object in the same scope as the other functions?**

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {})` missing closing `)` ? Where is `updateData` called ?, before `.ready()` event ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare the `var` outside of `$(document).ready` and then assign it's value without using `var`

```
var dataObject ;
$(document).ready(function() { 

    dataObject = new DataEntryObj(); // create the data object
    ......

});
```

This will now be equivalent to `window.dataObject`

Comment: This is giving me the following console error: Uncaught TypeError: DataEntryObj is not a function

Comment: then you have enclosed `DataEntryObj` function declaration inside another function probably. Functions are the same as variables when it comes to scope availability

Answer (score 1):

You can define a global variable, but you should make sure that `updateData` tries to access `dataObject` after DOM becomes accessible

```
var dataObject, DataEntryObj;

DataEntryObj = function(){
  this.dataArray = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0]];
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  dataObject = new DataEntryObj();

  $.post("../stageArea.php", {array : dataObject.dataArray}, function(data){
    $('#stageArea').html(data);
  });

}

function updateData(value, row, index) {
   // will have ref to dataObject changed by $(document)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access dataObject varailable. Because you setted in function. You should create a global object variable and you can access everywhere.

```
var dataObject = { data: null };

$(document).ready(function() { 

    dataObject.data = new DataEntryObj(); // create the data object

    $.post("../stageArea.php", {array : dataObject.data.dataArray}, function(data){
        $('#stageArea').html(data);
    });
  }
  var DataEntryObj = function(){
    this.dataArray = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0]];
  }

  function updateData(value, row, index){

    alert("update:" + row + " " + index + " " + value);
    alert(dataObject.data.dataArray[row][index]);  
    dataObject.data.dataArray[row][index] = value;

    $.post("../stageArea.php", {array : dataObject.data.dataArray}, function(data){
         $('#stageArea').html(data);
    });
}
```